# button isEnabled = true doesn`t works without mouse click WPF MVVM

Tags: wpf, user-interface, mvvm

I have wpf applicaton based on MVVM pattern.
I have annoying  issue and I can`t figure how can I solve it.

My application is wizard application, When the user press "Next" I am starting some progress in another thread (backgroundworker), when the bgWorker is starting he set `CanMoveNext = false` which binded to Next button isEnabled property and when the bgworker is finish he set back CanMoveNext = true;

When `CanMoveNext` get `IsEnabled = false` the UI show it immediately but after the isEnabled propery set back to true the UI do the refresh just after a mouse click or keyboard key press.

After I`m changing the property I`m using `OnPropertyChanged()` method, I even tried use  `CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested();` but it`s still not get refreshed without mouseclick.

How can I solve this problem?

Here is my code:

```
       public override bool CanMoveNext
        {
            get
            {
                return canMoveNext;
            }
            set
            {
                canMoveNext = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("CanMoveNext");
            }
        }



    public void StartProgress()
            {

                CanMoveNext = false;
                InitBGworkers(out bgStartPersonalWorker);
    bgStartPersonalWorker.RunWorkerAsync();
    }



        void bgStartPersonalWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            DoStuff();
        }



        void bgStartPersonalWorker_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
                {
     CanMoveNext = true;
//Even  CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested(); doen`t help
                }
```

//Code from XAML

```
<Button Content="{Binding ButtonNextCaption}" IsEnabled="{Binding CanMoveNext, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Command="{Binding Path=NavigateNextCommand}" Margin="5,0,5,0" Width="100" Height="40" FontSize="14" FontWeight="Bold"/>
```

Thanks

Comment: Just a wild shot, but have you tried setting the property from the UI thread? e.g. Setting the CanMoveNext using a `Dispatcher.Invoke`?

Comment: Ok i figure it out - your comment helped me fined a solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figure how solve it:

```
            Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new ThreadStart(() =>
            {
                CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested();

            }));
```

Comment: Using method group:
Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new ThreadStart(CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested));